# Disk space required by pg_basebackup

Tags: postgresql

I need to setup the PostgreSQL slave and i am using `pg_basebackup` to get the master data. However, is there any way to calculate the space required on slave before running `pg_basebackup`.

Answer (score 0):

pg_basebackup takes a file-level backup of the running database, so you can just see how much space is being used by the database currently.  If you're on linux, you can use du -s on the data directory.  The function pg_database_size('dbname') will also get you close, if you only have one database.

Comment: you can use `pg_database_size()` to sum the size of all databases: `select pg_database_size(datname) from pg_database`

Comment: That is already known. I want to read the space from another machine.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, sorry.  The space required will be the same on any machine.